# Remove only a trailing semi-colon

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

At first I tried:

```
update myTable set myColumn = replace(myColumn,';','')
```

However the data might have a valid `;` in the middle of the data. Before:

```
myColumn 
not;trailing
not;trailing and trailing; 
trailing;
```

After:

```
myColumn 
not;trailing
not;trailing and trailing
trailing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make good use of [`left`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) (or [`substring`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)) and [`len`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) in this case:

```
update myTable
set myColumn = left(myColumn, len(myColumn) - 1)
where myColumn like '%;'
```